# Tell RecycerView to fetch more items programmatically?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-paging

I'm using a RecyclerView in conjunction with `PagedListAdapter` to fetch images from a rest API. The RecyclerView fetches more images as needed when I scroll through it. I would like to simulate scrolling very fast through the RecyclerView but still have onBindViewHolder() get called for each item since the logic inside there is important. Ideally I would like to be at position 50 in the RecyclerView and be able to do something like `mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(300);` but that doesn't work since position `300` doesn't exist yet.

Is there a way to programmatically scroll the recyclerView so that it effectively does the same thing as me manually scrolling through it?

Comment: Do you want to smooth scroll to position 300? Or instantaneously scroll to it?

Comment: Seems that you need to adjust the settings in `PagedList.Config` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedList.Config.html#enablePlaceholders) so that either you allow for the list to be all the items, or increase the `prefetchDistance` so that when you are at position 50 the item in position 300 is prefetched.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `scrollTo()` as following

```
mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(POSITION_TO_SCROLL_TO);
        }
    });
```